# (Re)Assignment to a 2 dimensional std::vector<bool> within a private member function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, operator-keyword, stdvector

When implementing a class there is an internal object:

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> a;
```

The class initializes this object with the `operator[]` to assign `false`:

```
for(auto i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
    for(auto j = 0; j < limit; ++j) {
        a[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

During a private member function we update this object to reflect the current state, note that `object.x` and `object.y` are type `int` as is `new_x` and `new_y`:

```
a[object.x][object.y] = false;
a[new_x][new_y] = true;
```

The object class being used is:

```
class object {
public:
    object(): x(0), y(0) { }
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Why does the compiler allow for the initialization but then says:

```
error: expression is not assignable
```

when I am reassigning the bit in the vector in the private member function?

Here is a Minimal complete verifiable example:

Object.hpp:

```
 #ifndef OBJECT_HPP
 #define OBJECT_HPP

 class Object {
 public:
     Object(): x(0), y(0) {}
     Object(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
     int x;
     int y;
 };
 #endif`
```

main.cpp

```
   #include "Object.hpp"
   #include <vector>

   class Function {

       public:
           Function() : a(10, std::vector<bool>(10)) { }

           void moveObjects() {
               for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                   editObjects(i,i);
               }
           }

       private:
           void editObjects(int new_x, int new_y) const {
               a[new_x][new_y] = true;
            }


       std::vector<std::vector<bool>> a;
   };

   int main() {
       Function f;

       f.moveObjects();
   }
```

Using clang to compile receives the error:

`clang++-3.8 main.cpp -std=c++14`

Comment: Can we see your `object` class and also the call (location where you are assigning the new values)? Maybe there is something that needs to be set as `public`? And if you think the problem is with choosing `auto`, then change it to the basic `int` and try it.

Comment: Also, is the member function `const`?

Comment: Basically, you need to create a [mcve]

Comment: Inside which function do you do your initialization and inside which function the error happens?

Comment: Your `Function` constructor is totally wrong.  You are accessing elements that are out-of-bounds of the vector.  It should simply be: `Function() : a(10, std::vector<bool>(10)) { }`

Comment: I'd suggest getting rid of the two-dimensional vector... the C++ FAQ has a technique you can use for multidimensional arrays that works here too: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-array-of-array

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
void editObjects(int new_x, int new_y) const {
   a[new_x][new_y] = true;
}
```

That is not correct since you are now allowed to modify `a` in a `const` member function. Remove the `const` qualifier from the function.

```
void editObjects(int new_x, int new_y) {
   a[new_x][new_y] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the private member function is defined as `const` changing the object to be `mutable` resolves the issue:

```
mutable std::vector<std::vector<bool>> a;
```

Comment: The bit vector is being used as a cache for storing objects that will later have to be updated and re-cached. This object isn't the direct state of the world and is merely used for book keeping when the world changes, which makes me believe that `mutable` is ok here.

Comment: In that case, there are fewer problems with mutable! Just be sure to ensure thread-safety manually.